# Only show HTML body after a CSS animation is complete ( using pure css )

Tags: html, css, svelte

I am building a website and I made an animation in svelte / css. The animation draws out an SVG and the div the SVG sits inside of flies to top and off the screen and becomes invisible. This animation is to act as a transition screen, hiding the page content until it moves off the screen.

There is an issue. I the animation in my app.svelte and loading the page content in the index.html and whenever the animation starts, the scroll wheel is visible which allows the users to simply scroll down before the animation is done.

I am wondering if there are some solutions like maybe wrapping the page content in a div and adding a perfectly timed transition, or possibly something more simple.

I do not want to use js or jquery.

Code...

```
svg {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
  }
  .container {
    background-color: #091a28;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    animation: flyUp 2.75s forwards;
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }

  @keyframes flyUp {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-2000px);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you want to solve only by pure css then you will need to add `@keyframes` on `body` too for prevent `scrolling` like `(from{overflow:hidden} to{overflow:auto})` untill animation effect end.

Comment: So I should make another ```@keyframes``` on body until after my animation ends? Sounds simple enough... however it seems to my like using this method will result in my having to manually tune the animation ending and the body becoming visible at the same time. Is this the case, and if so, is there any built in css functions I can use to start an animation when another ends ( like a callback function but for CSS ), without having 2 separate animations.

Comment: Can you proved jsfiddle or codepen example? So I can more thought about your need.

Comment: For some reason that isn't working.. I cant really show a code pen because the file is kinda large. 

body {
  animation: bodyFade 6s;
}

@keyframes bodyFade {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  to {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

I tried doing this and it did not work.

Comment: You forgot to add **forwards** so its should be like `animation: bodyFade 6s forwards`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this **0%,99%{overflow: hidden;} 100%{overflow: auto;}** I have set position fixed of `.container` class to cover whole body view.
I hope below snippet will help you lot

```css
svg {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.container {
  background-color: #091a28;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: flyUp 2.75s forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
 @keyframes flyUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
} 

/*body scrollbar hide/show*/
body {
  animation: bodyFade 3.6s forwards;
}
@keyframes bodyFade{ 
  0%,99%{overflow: hidden;}
  100%{overflow: auto;}
} 

/*For Content*/
.content{
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg></svg>
</div>

<div class="content">
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <p>
  Last Line Paragraph...
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @RaeeshAlam , thank you for this answer. I was able to get this to work, however, for some reason scrolling is not working on my Iphone ( but is working on android phones ). Any ideas on what can be causing this issue?

Comment: You can try overflow property on both element (html & body). I hope it will work on iPhone too

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event. This will be fired when a CSS animation is completed.

You can hide the page contents and make them display in the callback function of the animationend event.

```js
headerAnimated = document.getElementById("header");

headerAnimated.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('Animation ended');
});
```

```css
@keyframes headerAnimation{
    0% {background-color:red}
    50% {background-color:yellow}
    100% {background-color:black}
}

h1{
    animation:headerAnimation 5s;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Animation</h1>
```

Comment: OP: *( using pure css )* and *I do not want to use js or jquery.*